# Update all posts in custom post type with wp_cron()

Tags: php, database, wordpress, cron

I have made a function to apply a taxonomy term to post, if it has a post meta value set to true. This works as should.
**The problem I am facing is that it only updates after I have manually saved/updated the post**. 
Is there any way to schedule this or do it dynamically for all posts inside the custom post type?

My code for the taxonomy term function:-

```
function save_cp_term_meta( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    $termshouldbe='new';

    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'new_used_cat', true ); 
        if  (!empty( $meta_value )) 
        { 
           $termshouldbe='used';
        }
        else 
        {
        } 

    wp_set_object_terms($post_id,$termshouldbe,'vehicle_condition',false);
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_cp_term_meta', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Hey Shaun, does this need to be run regularly (where cron would be a good option) or does it only need to be run once and all of the previous posts will be updated?

Comment: I have an import at 5pm each day, so each day preferably

Comment: I posted an answer that I think is a possible solution for your needs, if anything is unclear ask me to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WP_Cron()` to schedule a task to run at a specific time each day and perform the update.

```
// check if the next cron is ours, if not schedule it.
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'prefix_save_cp_term_meta_cron' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( strtotime( '5:15PM' ), 'daily', 'prefix_save_cp_term_meta_cron' );
}
/**
 * function to query for posts of a certain post type and update
 * some term_meta based on a post_meta value.
 */
function prefix_save_cp_term_meta_runner() {
    // make sure to set the correct post type you want here.
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => array( 'your post type' ),
        'meta_key'       => 'new_used_cat',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    // run the query.
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // if the query has posts...
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        // loop through them...
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            // default value to use as term.
            $termshouldbe = 'new';
            // get the current post_meta if it exists.
            $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'new_used_cat', true );
            if ( ! empty( $meta_value ) ) {
                // update the value for term based on having a value for new_used_cat.
                $termshouldbe = 'used';
                // NOTE: you may want to delete the post_meta here so that next
                // iteration this query doesn't need to work with this post
                // again as it's already processed.
            }
            // set the term with a value (either 'new' or 'used').
            wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, $termshouldbe, 'vehicle_condition', false );
        }
        // restore the main query.
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
} // End if().
add_action( 'prefix_save_cp_term_meta_cron', 'save_cp_term_meta_runner' );
```

NOTE: You may want to look at adding this in intervals instead of at a fixed time - or run it via a system level cron job instead. This answer details some issues when working with `WP_Cron()` that might help you decide which method is best for you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179774/37158

Comment: Hi William. Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it. when I paste into my functions it breaks the site? Any ideas on that?

Comment: Hey, apologies I did tweak the code after pulling it from my test site so I probably added a typo or something :( Let me look at this again shortly and I'll ping you when I fix it.

Comment: No worries William, I appreciate the help!

Comment: @ShaunPhillips hey, sorry I didn't get to this yesterday. I did have an issue in the code - an extra bracket. Should be fixed now.